Truffle Test Executed with 0 passing
I am new to blockchain and trying to learn blockchain using Etherium environment with ReactJS. For learning purpose, I am following below link:
https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/blockchain-tutorial
Everything is working as explained in above link till the test case executing step. When I run truffle test then codes compiled successfully but with 0 passing.
Below is my test case code written in reactJS:
const SocialNetwork = artifacts.require('./socialNetwork.sol')

require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised')).should()

contract('SocialNetwork', (accounts) => {
 let socialNetwork

 before(async () => {
   socialNetwork = await SocialNetwork.deployed()
 })

 describe('deployment', async () => {
   it('has a name', async () => {
     const name = await socialNetwork.name()
     assert.equal(name, 'Dapp Social Network')
   })
 })
})  

Below is the output after running truffle test:
truffle test
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\SocialNetwork.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\test--26480-U15AuvrMpfHd
> Compiled successfully using:
  - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang


0 passing (1ms)  

Why is my test case not executing?


mocha is already built in Truffle and it looks for test directory. make sure your test files in test directory.

check your contract name, make sure it has no typo. Based on your code
contract('SocialNetwork', (accounts) => {}



its name should be exactly SocialNetwork
